# Error installing rails api with postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cmd

I am trying to build a skeleton rails-api to use for future use but keep coming across an error. So i am in a folder call Rails_API_Skeleton and i run..

```
gem install rails-api
```

Which runs fine.
I then run...

```
rails-api new Skeleton_App -d postgresql -T
```

Which also runs without any issues. So i...

```
cd Skeleton_App/
```

then run...

```
bin/rake db:create
```

And get the following error, which after much googling i cant figure out how to resolve.

```
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:89:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'rails-api'.
Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant ActionController::API::RackDelegation
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rails-api-0.4.0/lib/rails-api/action_controller/api.rb:131:in `<class:API>'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rails-api-0.4.0/lib/rails-api/action_controller/api.rb:85:in `<module:ActionController>'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rails-api-0.4.0/lib/rails-api/action_controller/api.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rails-api-0.4.0/lib/rails-api.rb:3:in `require'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rails-api-0.4.0/lib/rails-api.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `require'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `each'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block in require'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:102:in `require'
/Users/username/Desktop/Apple_tv_movies_and_stuff/skeletons/Rails_API_Skeleton/Skeleton_App/config/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `require'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `preload'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
 (Bundler::GemRequireError)
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `each'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block in require'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:102:in `require'
    from /Users/username/Desktop/Apple_tv_movies_and_stuff/skeletons/Rails_API_Skeleton/Skeleton_App/config/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `require'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `preload'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1):

I suspect something changed with the gem in response to Rails 5.
Maybe its use is deprecated now?
Anyway, the new Rails API way seems to be

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html

```
rails new skeleton_api --api
```